# Django REST framework returning empty queryset even though the shell/print returns items

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My JSON response to `GET http://localhost:8000/v1/tags/search` is

```json
[]
```

But it should contain a list of tags.

I've registered the route with DRF:

```py
router.register(r"tags/search", TagSearchViewSet, basename='tag-search-list')
```

The view:

```py
from taggit.models import Tag

class TagSearchViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = TagSearchSerializer
    paginator = None

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Tag.objects.all()
        print(queryset)
        return queryset
```

The serializer:

```py
from taggit.models import Tag

class TagSearchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = '__all__'
```

That `print()` statement prints out

```bash
<QuerySet [<Tag: something>, <Tag: else>, <Tag: mytag2>, <Tag: mytag1>, <Tag: mytag3>, <Tag: mytag4>]>
```

In `python manage.py shell` I can also print out tags using

```bash
> from taggit.models import Tag
> tags = Tag.objects.all()
> tags
  <QuerySet [<Tag: something>, <Tag: else>, <Tag: mytag2>, <Tag: mytag1>, <Tag: mytag3>, <Tag: mytag4>]>
```

So why is the response an empty list?

Comment: Is this the same ViewSet class you're using? or is there any filtering somewhere?

Comment: Just this viewset registered with the router, and the `print` is called so it's being used. No filtering, just `all()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a permission issue. Adding `filter_backends = []` to the `TagSearchViewSet` fixed it.